# how to find declaration of a predicate in the modules which lie in other directories

Tags: plugins, prolog, declaration, predicate, sicstus-prolog

For Prolog plugins, such as SICStus [spider](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/spider/site/index.html), [proDT](http://prodevtools.sourceforge.net/) and [PDT](http://roots.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/), "find declaration" in eclipse editor can not find predicate definition in the modules which lie in different directories.

For example,

```
$HOME/dirA/A.pl:
    :- module(database,[]).
    ...
    set_dbaccess(Options) :-
      (db_done ->
           true
           ; 
    ...

$HOME/dirB/B.pl:
    ...
    fd(From,To,OrigOptions) :-
       database:set_dbaccess(OrigOptions),
    ...
```

There is no import statement for module `database` in the top of B.pl. so all the above plugins cannot find the definition for module `database` and predicate `set_dbaccess`.  Of course, the F3 operations on symbols `database, set_dbaccess` also fail.

any methods for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what exactly you want but I guess 
you can make a file say pred_files containing :-dynamic pred1/2, pred2/3, ... and
every time you need use the predicate in another .pl file you can use :-ensure_loaded(pred_files)